# How to add MKPolyline to mapView after viewDidLoad() has been called?

Tags: swift, mapkitannotation

I currently have an app that when a button is pushed a `MKPolyline` is supposed to be displayed on my `mapView`.

When I call the `MKPolyline` function in `viewDidLoad()` the polyline is displayed on the `mapView`. If I try and call the function using the button action function and not `viewDidLoad()` the `MKPolyline` does not get displayed.

Depending on which button is pressed determines which polyline should be displayed.

**How do I get the `MKPolyline` to be displayed?**

My `MapViewController` code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, 
CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView?

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView?.delegate = self
        mapView?.showsUserLocation = true

        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

        onLoadMapView()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    let location1:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.7484445, -73.9878531)
    let location2:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.758899, -73.9873197)
    let location3:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.7058134, -73.9981622)
    let location4:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.6892534, -74.0466891)

    func onLoadMapView() {
        let distanceSpan:CLLocationDegrees = 500

    mapView?.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(
            location1,
            distanceSpan,
            distanceSpan
        ), animated: true)
    }

    func mapPolylineView(buttonNo: NSNumber) {
        let sourceCoordinates = locationManager.location?.coordinate
        var destCoordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

        if buttonNo == 1 {
            destCoordinates = location1
        } else if buttonNo == 2 {
            destCoordinates = location2
        } else if buttonNo == 3 {
            destCoordinates = location3
        } else if buttonNo == 4 {
            destCoordinates = location4
        }

        let sourceItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceCoordinates!)
        let destItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: destCoordinates!)

        let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
        directionRequest.source = sourceItem
        directionRequest.destination = destItem
        directionRequest.transportType = .walking

        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
        directions.calculate(completionHandler: {
            response, error in
            guard let response = response else {
                if error != nil {
                    print("Something went wrong")
                }
                return
            }

            let route = response.routes[0]
            self.mapView?.add(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)

            let rekt = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
            self.mapView?.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rekt), animated: true)
        })
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 69/255, green: 0/255, blue: 132/255, alpha: 1)
        renderer.lineWidth = 5.0

        return renderer
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want to do? do you want to display only one polyline at the moment?

Comment: yes, but only after the user selects a button. If they go to the map without pushing a button it should not show a polyline

Comment: Try to add your polyline in the main thread. Did you check in the debugger that your code is ececuted?